Beginner is stuck with EXCEL ETL
I just don't know where to begin the ETL adventure. I have a multi-row header messy dataset provided by an archaic ERP software. I just need to clean it to become suitable for basic pivot/vlookups and maybe power BI.
Do you think I should go the VBA route or power query?
Any other suggestions are highly appreciated because my brain is boiling..
Thank you!
before

after

Here is the VBA I've used but it is buggy vba
Sub TransformDataToSingleRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim headers As Collection
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim valueDict As Object
                     
    ' Set up the worksheet and output row
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    destRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 2 ' Output starts 2 rows below data
    
    ' Store all unique headers into a collection
    Set headers = New Collection
    Set valueDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' For mapping headers to values
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the sheet
    For currentRow = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In ws.Rows(currentRow).Cells
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                ' Check if it's a header: text followed by a value in the next cell
                If cell.Value Like "*:*" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
                    On Error Resume Next ' Prevent duplicates in the collection
                    headers.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                    ' Add value to dictionary
                    valueDict(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
                
                ' Capture tabular data with headers from the last row
                If ws.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = "Due Date" Then
                    lastCol = ws.Cells(currentRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    For col = 1 To lastCol
                        On Error Resume Next
                        headers.Add ws.Cells(currentRow, col).Value, ws.Cells(currentRow, col).Value
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        valueDict(ws.Cells(currentRow, col).Value) = ws.Cells(currentRow + 1, col).Value
                    Next col
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    Next currentRow
    
    ' Output headers and values to a single row
    Dim header As Variant
    Dim destCol As Long
    destCol = 1
    
    ' Output headers in the first row
    For Each header In headers
        ws.Cells(destRow, destCol).Value = header
        destCol = destCol + 1
    Next header
    
    ' Output values in the second row
    destCol = 1
    For Each header In headers
        ws.Cells(destRow + 1, destCol).Value = valueDict(header)
        destCol = destCol + 1
    Next header
    
    MsgBox "Transformation complete!", vbInformation
End Sub


I would suggest using VBA.
Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.

"Do you think I should go the VBA route or power query?" - are you familiar with either of those?  Screenshot is a bit confusing - you've included the row and column headers but there's another set?  Presumably that second set is not part of your data?

@taller hello, here is a code that my good friend ChatGPT gave me but it is not working and I'm using a free version and ran out of computes for the day.
can't add more that 400 characters....

Does the ERP software export data in CSV or XLS format? If it's in CSV, your ETL process should start with the CSV file rather than an Excel worksheet.

@taller it spits out an excel exactly how it looks on the 1st picture.

Bit rough but works:
Sub ExpandTable()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, cDest As Range, headers
    Dim c As Range, numRows As Long
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dest")
    
    Set cDest = wsDest.Range("A1")
    
    headers = Array( _
       "ITEM", "Description", "Current Stock", "Unit", "Min.", "Max", _
       "Due Date", "Type", "Transaction", "With", "Required", "Received", _
       "Net", "MRP Order", "Prod. On Hand", "Locat.")
    
    cDest.Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1).Value = headers 'add all headers
    Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1)
    
    Set c = wsSrc.Range("A1") 'start here on the source sheet
    Do While c.Row <= wsSrc.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If c.Value Like "Item:*" Then  'data block header?
            numRows = 0 'reset, and then count how many rows in the table below
            Do While Len(c.Offset(5 + numRows)) > 0
                numRows = numRows + 1
            Loop
            'populate the data, starting with the repeated values
            cDest.Resize(numRows, 1).Value = Trim(Replace(Split(c.Value, ",")(0), "Item:", ""))
            cDest.Offset(0, 1).Resize(numRows, 1).Value = Trim(Split(c.Value, ",")(1))
            cDest.Offset(0, 2).Resize(numRows, 1).Value = c.Offset(2, 2).Value
            cDest.Offset(0, 3).Resize(numRows, 1).Value = c.Offset(2, 4).Value
            cDest.Offset(0, 4).Resize(numRows, 1).Value = c.Offset(2, 6).Value
            cDest.Offset(0, 5).Resize(numRows, 1).Value = c.Offset(2, 8).Value
            'copy the table...
            cDest.Offset(0, 6).Resize(numRows, 10).Value = c.Offset(5).Resize(numRows, 10).Value
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(numRows) 'next destination
            Set c = c.Offset(numRows + 4)     'skip copied data
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub


thanks. I had to rename my active sheet to "source" and create a new one called "Dest" to run the macro. The error is in this line [     cDest.Resize(numRows, 1).Value = Trim(Replace(Split(c.Value, ",")(0), "Item:", ""))    ]

What's the value of numRows when that fails?

...and the source/destination sheet names are just examples - you can change them (and/or the source/destination workbooks) to whatever makes sense for your setup.

it stops processing at ~30% mark of my dirty data, spits out a perfect dataset in "dest" sheet up until row # 1556. The code is awesome, if you only could make it run through the whole dirty data!

the numRows = 0 just like i copied from your above code

the code returns an error after processing a random number of rows. After I clear the cells after the problematic row in the original dataset the code advances further (when re-run) and stops after another random # rows. Then, I clear the dirty rows right after the last good data again, re-run the macro and the code processes more data, rinse and repeat. There is nothing particularly different in the deleted cells, they are all identical, no special characters or leading spaces...

If you're able to share a full example export which has that problem, I will leave my email here...

It should be fairly simple in powerquery.  Bring your entire range into powerquery with data ... from table/range and do not tick the headers box
Go into home advanced editor and paste
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom",  each try if Text.Contains([Column1],"Item:") then [Index] else null otherwise null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Column1] <> null)),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"data", each 
    let  a=_,
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Skip(a,2)),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Item", each Text.BetweenDelimiters(a{0}[Column1],": ",",")),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Description", each Text.AfterDelimiter(a{0}[Column1],",")),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Current Stock", each a{1}[Column3]),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Unit", each a{1}[Column5]),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Minimum", each a{1}[Column7]),
    #"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom5", "Maximum", each a{1}[Column9])   
    in  #"Added Custom6", type table }}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Custom"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", {"Item", "Description", "Current Stock", "Unit", "Minimum", "Maximum","Due Date", "Type", "Transaction", "With", "Required", "Received", "Net", "MRP Order", "Prod on Hand", "Loc" }, {"Item", "Description", "Current Stock", "Unit", "Minimum", "Maximum","Due Date", "Type", "Transaction", "With", "Required", "Received", "Net", "MRP Order", "Prod on Hand", "Loc" })
in  #"Expanded data"

file ... close and load it back into excel as a table or pivot


fantastic! But, the magic stops with the "Transaction" column. The following columns are all "null": with/required/received/net/mrp order/prod on hand/loc

Its hard to tell exactly since you didn't provide sample data and I had to type in what I think it looked like. Sorry

My approach would be Power Query. You probably can do all that by clicking ribbon buttons. In order:

load the sheet
Create a custom column that extracts the text of the first column, but only if the text starts with "Item:"
Fill that column down
delete the first four rows
set the (now) first row as headers
set the data type of the Due Date column as Date
that will produce errors for all the rows that are not date
remove all rows with errors
split the custom column you created in step 2 by the delimiter ": "
split the split-off column by the delimiter ", "
rename columns as desired and delete unwanted helper columns
set correct data types
Save and load.


Both rows 1 and 3 need to become columns filled down

@horseyride Yes, I missed that, but my answer is about the concept rather than a complete solution. Teach'em how to fish.

Load the source table into an array, process the data, and write the output back to the sheet.
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, sVal
    Const KEY_COL = 2 ' change to 1 if col A on source sheet is blank
    Const HEADER = "Item,Description,Current Stock,Unit,Minimum,Maximum,Due Date,Type,Transaction,With,Required,Received,Net,MRP Order,Prod on Hand,Locat."
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet:  Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")    ' Source sheet
    Dim oSht2 As Worksheet: Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")     ' Dest. sheet
    ' load data into array
    Set rngData = oSht1.UsedRange
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Dim RowCnt As Long: RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    Dim ColCnt As Long: ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    Dim arr, sItem(5) As String
    ReDim arrRes(RowCnt, 1 To ColCnt - KEY_COL + 7) ' store the output
    ' load header row
    For Each sVal In Split(HEADER, ",")
        i = i + 1
        arrRes(0, i) = sVal
    Next
    ' loop through rows
    For i = LBound(arrData) To RowCnt
        ' check the start cell with "Item:*"
        If arrData(i, KEY_COL) Like "Item:*" Then
            arr = Split(arrData(i, KEY_COL), ",")
            sItem(0) = "'" & Trim(Split(arr(0))(1))
            sItem(1) = Trim(arr(1))
            For j = 1 To 4
                sItem(j + 1) = arrData(i + 2, KEY_COL + 2 * j)
            Next
            For j = i + 5 To RowCnt
                If Len(arrData(j, KEY_COL)) = 0 Then
                    i = j - 1
                    Exit For
                ElseIf IsDate(arrData(j, KEY_COL)) Then ' detail row
                    iR = iR + 1
                    For k = 1 To UBound(arrRes, 2)
                        If k < 7 Then
                            arrRes(iR, k) = sItem(k - 1)
                        Else
                            arrRes(iR, k) = arrData(j, k - 5)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    oSht2.Cells.Clear
    ' write output to sheet
    oSht2.Range("A1").Resize(iR + 1, UBound(arrRes, 2)).Value = arrRes
End Sub



it only gives me the first row with future headers: Item Description Current Stock Unit Minimum Maximum Due Date Type Transaction With Required Received Net MRP Order Prod on Hand Locat.
that's it

@PavloKobzar The script has been tested (check the snapshot in my answer) using the sample data shown in your snapshot. If it isn't working during your testing, it might be due to differences in the layout of your actual data file.
